# How can I redirect to the login view in case the user is not logged in?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am doing the validations of my Logueo view, and I want that if the user is not logged in, he cannot access the Index, I want to force him to register yes or yes.

From what I was seeing, it can be done with the `ActionFilterAttribute` class, and then validating that a `Session` variable is not null, in case it is, it automatically redirects you to Login.

My problem is that I am developing my application in `ASP.NET Core`, and from what I understood, `Session` cannot be used in `Core`, and you have to use other alternatives like `TempData[]` or `Cookies` .

Could someone explain me better why `Session` cannot be used and if they can help me with redirecting the user to the Login view in case he is not logged in?

```
public class ValidateSession: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    { 
        if(HttpContext.Session.GetString("User") == null)
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/Login");
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);    
    }
}
```

> An Object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HttpContext.Session'

Comment: From your question it looks like you haven't implemented any user authentication/authorization yet in your project. You can check this article to implement cookie authentication: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0.

Comment: With that is not necessary the Session?

Comment: Yes, session is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Session. You simply need to add the below snippet to your `Program.cs` file:

```
builder.Services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter());
});
```

This is assuming that you're using Identity to manage your users and the MVC middleware. Also make sure that you're using the `MVC.Authorization` package within your `Program.cs` file.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
```